# Image not showing up in Redactor text editor

Tags: redactor, image, richtext

When i try to add an image in a bit of text, it does not show up. I get the assets model and can choose an image, but the image itself seems broken in the text.

I also see this error in the craft.log:

```
2015/07/27 13:57:03 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.404] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php:59
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Craft\TemplatesController->actionRender('entries/over/as...', Array)
#1 /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CAction.php(109): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Craft\TemplatesController), Array)
#2 /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(47): CAction->runWithParamsInternal(Object(Craft\TemplatesController), Object(ReflectionMethod), Array)
#3 /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#4 /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#5 /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#6 /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('render')
#7 /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('templates/rende...')
#8 /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(279): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#9 /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(184): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#10 /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#11 /Applications/AMPPS/www/jipfish/index.php(19): require_once('/Applications/A...')
#12 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/jipfish/admin/entries/over/assets/article/bolderkar_01.jpg
HTTP_REFERER=http://localhost/jipfish/admin/entries/over/5-about
---
2015/07/27 13:57:03 [error] [application] 
******************************************************************************************************
```

Does anyobe know what is up?

Thanks, Bob

Comment: "but the image itself seems broken in the text." Can you elaborate on what that means?  If you "view source" in redactor, what's the URL to the image look like?

Comment: Hi Brad, the image in the text does not load and you see a broken image icon. The src is relative to the site root and point correctly to an image in the assets folder, but it does not load in the text editor. However, it does load in the actual site, but without an image transform (so it's way to big).

Comment: Does it work if you try it without using it as an image transform?

Comment: I am not using a image transform at all. Just selecting an image through the assets modal after which it places the image in the text,  after which it does not show up.